# Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException while connecting to the Elastic Cloud instance

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud, elasticsearch-java-api-client

I am trying to connect to elastic cloud instance from my spring boot application. I want to index document from my application to elasticsearch instance.

This is my configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class ESConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public RestClientBuilder getBuilder() {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
                AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic","xxxxxx"));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("https://alerts-2d85d7.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io",443,"https"));
        builder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        });
        return builder;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTransport getElasticsearchTransport() {
        return new RestClientTransport(getBuilder().build(), new JacksonJsonpMapper());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient getElasticsearchClient() {
        return new ElasticsearchClient(getElasticsearchTransport());
    }   
}
```

I don't know if this is right way to connect to cloud instance, I did not find anything in documentation, I just followed similar way we connect to the local instance of elasticsearch.

I am getting below error

```
java.io.IOException: https://alerts-2d85d7.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:937) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:146) ~[elasticsearch-java-7.17.6.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:939) ~[elasticsearch-java-7.17.6.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:956) ~[elasticsearch-java-7.17.6.jar:na]
    at com.shrikant.ElasticRespository.createOrUpdateDocument(ElasticRespository.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.shrikant.ElasticRespository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1eb1709b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.shrikant.ElasticRespository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf06d34.createOrUpdateDocument(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.shrikant.Controller.createDocument(Controller.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: https://alerts-2d85d7.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:666) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:637) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:474) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.lease(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:280) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:295) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.requestConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:381) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:130) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:116) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:138) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: If these are your real credentials for that host, you should now rotate them immediately

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I deleted the instance,I did not look, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this:

```
new HttpHost("https://alerts-2d85d7.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io",443,"https")
```

By

```
new HttpHost("alerts-2d85d7.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io",443,"https")
```

Or use:

```
new HttpHost("https://alerts-2d85d7.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:443")
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: I think your endpoint is not correct. Or the URL tou shared is not the right one. Could you curl the endpoint?

Comment: No I can't, I am trying this setup in corporate network. But I can visit the endpoint from browser.